# terminal command to record video

Tags: command-line, video, webcam, cheese

I have `cheese` software in order to record a video and also take a picture from my laptop camera. But when you open that. you should do two thing: 1.Select video recording among its default taking photo option)  2. start to play ( start to record)

I need a command line when you put it on the terminal. cheese start to recording video without any other mouse click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `avconv`.

According to [manpage for the `avconv` command [image: Manpage icon]](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/avconv.1.html)

> avconv is a very fast video and audio converter that can also grab from
>          a live audio/video source.

There are many options in avconv, but for recording the screen, the command would be like

```
avconv -f x11grab -s 1024x768 -r 50 -t 500 -i :0.0 ~/Videos/name.mp4
```

Here,

```
-f: format for input file, x11grab for recording screen
-s: resolution, can be axb(eg. 1024x768) or some predefined words like hd1080
-r: rate(or bitrate).
-t: time, as seconds(500) or HH:MM:SS.[XXX](eg 01:04:59 or 01:56:43.111)
-i: input, here :0.0 generally
Finally the output file name
```

Comment: thanks for your help and answer, is this software has this ability to record via my laptop camera? What I am looking for is that.

Comment: @alex Yes, it can record from any input source like webcam, video file or screen. But I don't know what the name would be for webcam.

Comment: @alex Here's something that can help you. http://arashafiei.wordpress.com/2012/10/12/capture-video-and-audio-from-webcam-using-ffmpeg/

Comment: I appreciate your help